# Telephone regexes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

The following are all valid format for telephone number (note there can be leading and trailing spaces):

- 555-444-3333
- (555)-(444)-(3333)
- 5554443333
- 5554443333
- 5554443333
- 555 444 3333
- 555 4443333
- 555444 3333
- (5554443333)
- (555-444-3333)

How can I validate using Regex or Javascript in .NET?

Comment: does this really need strict validation? what about international numbers? Is 1-555-444-3333 not also valid?

Comment: I am with Jonathan. It is very unlikely that this validation will catch an accidentally mistyped entry. But it might very well make it impossible to enter valid but unusual numbers.

Comment: I agree with Jonathan and Thilo: my full phone number doesn't match the proposed patterns.

Comment: If you want to support international numbers, have a drop-down menu to allow the user to select their country, then validate the number according to the conventions of the selected country.  While this is technically straightforward, it will be terribly tedious and error-prone, and you might find it difficult to come up with the phone number formats for every country on the planet.

Comment: @Don, sadly edge cases still defeat that scenario. Real world example: A person has a UK skype phone number for his business, even though he was living in Japan at the time. If he selects Japan in the drop down, he can't use his phone number. If he selects United Kingdom, then his package will be mailed to the wrong country.

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't use a regular expression directly.  I'd copy each character to a new string, while skipping parantheses, hyphens and spaces.  Then check that the resulting string has ten characters, all of which are digits.

I don't know about .Net regexes, but ^[0-9]*$ is the way most regex libraries will verify that a string is entirely digits.

Alternatively you can use the standard library isdigit() function to check the characters one-by-one as you scan through them.

Comment: I thought of a simple stripping all the non numerics, like  s.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');, then check the length to be 10. This assumes 1 will not be entered as the first digit. But the user can copy paste some thing like (5554443333) or (555)-(444)-(3333) and it should still be valid..

Comment: this is only for US phone numbers

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function isPhoneNumber(x) { 
    return /^[0-9\-\(\)\s]*$/.test(x) && x.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'').length == 10; 
}
```

I share the concerns of some of the commenters but it does what you're asking for.

The first half of the test will fail if the string contains anything else than digits, hyphens, parens or spaces. The second half of the test will fail if the number of digits in the string is not 10.

Comment: Maybe only replace parentheses, dashes and spaces, otherwise 555aZ$444~~~33%33 would be valid. Though not really a big deal.